# Send Headername and Headerkey Trougth Browser

Tags: service, fiddler

I have added security to one of my services, and I would like to test it, 
Is there some way of adding the Key and Name in the Header? 
How can I do that in Fiddler, What do I have to type?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add a custom header to all outbound requests, go to the FILTERS tab and in the Request Headers section, add your custom header.